# Steps that I could take to troubleshoot a network connection for a desktop (no wifi)

Tags: networking, lan, ethernet

This is my first post, so don't judge if I mess something up.

The problem is that I bought a new Desktop PC for my office (a Windows 8 machine with motherboard Z97-HD3 (has integrated Ethernet/LAN card)) and it worked OK for a few weeks, but now, the internet is gone.

When I boot up my PC I get "Network Identifying". After a minute or so, it says that it is connected, but when I open a browser it either says: "This webpage is not available" (more often) or "SSL certificate problem" (rarely). I've been chipping on this problem for a few days and the only steps that I've mustered up to take are these:

**1. Is it the cable? Try the Ethernet/LAN cable on a different computer**

Tried that. It works on my other laptop. So I conclude that the problem is with the new computer.

**2. Is it a software problem or hardware?**

2.1. Look at the back of the PC. The Ethernet card lights are on.

2.2. Try pinging localhost. Start > Open command prompt (cmd) > "ping 127.0.0.1". All 4 packages are sent and received with time 1ms

2.3. Maybe there is something wrong with Windows? Tried installing Ubuntu, but the internet doesn't connect as well

Anything else I could do? Or should I conclude that this is a hardware issue and return it to the shop?

Comment: tried pinging my default gateway. Sometimes it works and sometimes not. How can I troubleshoot if its the ethernet card/is it the cable/or is it the router?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you can ping your Gateway (gateways are computers/routers that are between two networks ). You can find out the IP of your gateway by running this in cmd:

> ipconfig

There you will see your currently assigned(or static) ipaddress, the subnetwork, as well as the IP of your Gateway. Then try to ping your Gateway.

If you can then you know that all is good with cables and software and the problem is either configuration(you dont have gateway set) or the gateway can't make the connection outside of your local network.

if you can't ping your gateway, then you know something is wrong on your PC.